# Batch: "%~1" works, but "%~*" is a syntax error. How do I find the equivalent command?

Tags: batch-file

Batch: `"%~1"` works, but `"%~*"` is a syntax error.

How do I find the equivalent command?

Comment: There isn't one!

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do with "`%~*`"

Comment: The "equivalent command" to do what? If you want to _remove quotes from all parameters_: `set "args=%*"` and `set "args=%args:"=%"`. Tested...

Comment: @Aacini That will also remove the quotes that could be *inside* parameters.

Comment: @BladeMight: Please, post a _working_ example of a parameter with quotes inside it, so we can test the method...

Comment: @Aacini See my answer's last example.

Comment: @BladeMight: In [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52910619/778560) there is not any example of **calling a Batch file with a parameter with quotes _inside it_**. I need such an example in order to use _the same parameter_ to test my method (that you said that it _"will also remove the quotes that could be inside parameters"_).

Comment: @Aacini For example: say your way is in `bat.cmd` and my way in `bat2.cmd`(last code from my answer) calling from cmd: `bat.cmd "all""  args" "23"` returns `all  args 23`, calling `bat2.cmd "all""  args" "23"` returns `all""  args 23`, see? Your way removes `""` after all, my way removes only the ones around every argument

Comment: @Aacini - It is easy to put quotes within a batch parameter, but there are restrictions. There must be an even number of quotes, and there can be no token delimiters in any unquoted portion. For example, this is all one parameter: `" 1 2 "3" 4 5 "`

Comment: @Aacini - Correction - there can be an odd number of quotes, but everything on the line after the last quote will then be part of the same parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Since `%*` its `batch parameter is a wildcard reference to all the arguments not including %0`, you can't use `~` on it, but you can for loop on all arguments and `%%~` them, example:

```
for %%x in (%*) do (
    echo %%~x
)
```

Also if you need to combine them into single argument you can use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` with this loop:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set args=
for %%x in (%*) do (
  set args=!args! %%~x
)
echo %args:~1%
```

explain:

1. `!args!` is another way to use variable when using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`
2. `%args:~1%` remove first space.

And here is example without `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, which does not eat `!` symbols from arguments:

```
set args=
for %%x in (%*) do call :SETARGS %%x
GOTO :END
:SETARGS
set args=%args% %~1
:END
echo %args:~1%
```

Comment: The OP does not specify what they're trying to do. If their input string, `%1`, has the value `"converting to the metric system, 1" is just over 25mm."`, would the output be `converting to the metric system, 1" is just over 25mm.`?

Comment: The OP is very unclear for which purpose he wants to remove all double quotes from all parameters or whatever he expects on usage of `%~*`. The second version using delayed expansion produces on execution of batch file with `"C:\Temp\Exclamation Mark! in File Name!.txt"` as output `C:\Temp\Exclamation Mark.txt` and so corrupted this full qualified file name argument.

Comment: @Mofi See updated answer, I added another method without using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Comment: Yes, the third solution is better than second one as working also for argument strings with one or more `!`. But all solutions currently posted fail on calling the batch file with `"First Argument" SecondArgument "<Third Argument>" "& Last Argument"`. I don't think there can be a valid answer as long as OP does not post why to remove all `"` from all arguments which are required by `cmd.exe` on an argument string containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<|>`` as described by last help page of `cmd` output on running `cmd /?`.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the quotes from around all parameters and still keep them in one variable using something like the following:

```dos
@ECHO off

echo %*

set args=%~1
echo %args%
shift

:Clean
if [%1]==[] goto:End
set args=%args% %~1
shift
goto:Clean

:End

echo %args%
```

This uses the `shift` command to cycle through each parameter, remove the quotes and append it to the `args` environment variable.

**Further reading:**

- [Shift - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html)
- [Goto - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)

Comment: We don't know what Mario Palumbo wants to achieve at all with `%~*` which `cmd.exe` does not support according to help output on running `call /?` in a command prompt window. Your batch file could be useful for original poster, but results in an exit of batch file execution because of a syntax error on execution with `"First Argument" SecondArgument "<Third Argument>" "& Last Argument"`. BTW: `[%1]==[]` is not good because of `[` and `]` have no special meaning. Better would be using `"%~1" == ""` although this results in exiting loop on one parameter being just `""` without additional code.